# How could I list details of only 1 Azure Virtual Machines using Python?

Tags: python, azure, sdk, virtual-machine

I’ve used the below code to get the Access Token from my Azure account.

https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-python/blob/dev/sample/certificate_credentials_sample.py

It’s working fine, I already got the token as well

But when I use below statement, its listing all VM's information, but I need only for one VM
I referred to documentation, but it does not have any example for filtering

```
from azure.mgmt.compute import ComputeManagementClient
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials


Subscription_Id = "xxxxx"
Tenant_Id = "xxxxx"
Client_Id = "xxxxx"
Secret = "xxxxx"

credential = ServicePrincipalCredentials(
        client_id=Client_Id,
        secret=Secret,
        tenant=Tenant_Id
        )

compute_client = ComputeManagementClient(credential, Subscription_Id)

vm_list = compute_client.virtual_machines.list_all()
```

How to filter one VM and to output of all vm related info to json

Comment: You'd need to use the get() method.  i.e. ```vm = compute_client.virtual_machines.get(<resource group>, <vm name>)```

Comment: What detail do you know about the VM you want to get?

Comment: I need to know about, tags, disk , storage size etc for a given single vm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `get` method like this (preferred):

```py
vm = compute_client.virtual_machines.get(GROUP_NAME, VM_NAME, expand='instanceView')
```

But, if you wanted to do it with `list_all()`, you could do something like this:

```py
vm_list = compute_client.virtual_machines.list_all()

filtered = [vm for vm in vm_list if vm.name == "YOUR_VM_NAME"] #All VMs that match

vm = filtered[0] #First VM

print(f"vm size: {vm.hardware_profile.vm_size}")
```

You can refer to the docs and example link to see other properties available.

[Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/python#get-information-about-the-vm)

[Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-compute/azure.mgmt.compute.v2019_12_01.operations.virtualmachinesoperations?view=azure-python#get-resource-group-name--vm-name--expand-none--custom-headers-none--raw-false----operation-config-)

Comment: hi is there way to know which resource group my vm belongs to ?

Comment: you can view the resource group in azure portal; all resources and you would just need the name of the resource group for the python code. If you want to do it with code, you may need to use `compute_client.virtual_machines.list_all()` method and then manually filter out for the VM name your looking for then you can access information about it; updated an example in this answer with list all.